# Mac texmaker: How to gain access to "usr/texbin"?

Tags: texmaker, mac

I have spent the whole afternoon working on bibliography using texmaker and I still cannot get the bibliography.
My attempt is to use `biber` as in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-N2qtTnP1sg

The figure below is the place I hope to change the setting so that I can use `biber`.
[image]

I hope to change `usr/texbin/bibtex" %.aux` to `/usr/texbin/biber %.bcf` but I don't know if `biber` is in `usr/texbin`. There is a `texbin` folder but it is not under `/usr/`. It is `/opt/local/libexec/texlive/texbin` and there is no `biber`. How to locate `usr/texbin` out so that I can see if I have `biber`?

Comment: If all other programs work with that setting, then also `"/usr/texbin/biber" %.bcf` should work.

Comment: But the problem is I do not know if `/usr/texbin` contains `biber` or not. I tried that and I cannot compile the bibliography.

Comment: Did you install MacTeX 2015 recently and also ran Setup-2015.pkg?

Comment: I forgot if I have MacTex or not. I think I installed MiKTeX. I started using Tex one year ago in this macbook and installed all the required package and texmaker in 2014 summer in the macbook. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, you can't have MiKTeX on Mac OS X. You may have installed TeX Live with MacPorts, which would be a bad thing. Go to http://tug.org/mactex and install MacTeX 2015.

Comment: Thanks. But I am near my deadline of submission. So i don't hope to risk reinstalling things. Is there an alternative solution on how to do bibliography in Mac Texmaker? I tried biblatex (as in the above figure without changing anything and use `\usepackage[sorting=none, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`), `\usepackage{bibtex}` and the above biber but they do not work. What do you recommend? Should I try `natbib` and is there a way that I can just download `biber` into `/usr/texbin/`? I typed out the bibliography myself before without `bib.` file.

Comment: Well you do not need to reinstall anything. You simple need to paste the real path to the biber binary file. In gnu/linux the path `/usr/texbin` could be right in many cases. But in Mac it's different and you need to find it. Otherwise you can use the default mactex text editor. I don't remember the name right now. There you can find an script for run your bibliographies and compile them well. I used it a couple of times and it does the job well. Maybe you need to setup the encoding before if you're using something different from MacOS Roman in TeXmaker.

Comment: @Aradnix `/usr/texbin` is right for Mac OS X if MacTeX is installed. It would generally ***not*** be right on GNU/Linux. I don't understand why you are suggesting use of the MacTeX default editor when (a) the user has an editor and (b) it is not clear that MacTeX is installed at all. Etc.

Comment: @kwy Can you compile your file with those settings? Never mind the bibliography - just does it work to just do the basic compile? If so, get a command line (Terminal is the application on OS X) and type `which pdflatex` and `which biber`. If you get a result for the first but not the second, you maybe don't have Biber, although this would be odd. You can use the `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` option. But delete the loading of `bibtex`. Delete generated files from your working directory and compile. There is no such package. You cannot just download Biber and add it, no.

Comment: Note that you must run `biber` (if you have it, as is very likely) or `bibtex` after running `pdflatex`. Then you must run `pdflatex` again, possibly twice or more. So `pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex`. If you are using something other than `pdflatex`, that's fine. Any LaTeX will work (`latex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex`).

Comment: Thanks. `which pdflatex` returns `/opt/local/bin/pdflatex` while `which biber` returns `/usr/texbin/biber`. So I guess I have `biber` and better still it is under `/usr/texbin`. @cfr

Comment: @cfr Thank you for the sequence of buttoms I have to push also. I have not tried it yet. Does it apply to the main `.tex` file  or `.bib` file or both? Do I just need to save `.bib`? Before I just push `biber` (after adding a new command) + quick build and bibliography does not appear.

Comment: It looks like you have two versions of TeX installed. Mixing them is bad. So either you have to know exactly what you are doing and ensure they do not mix, or you should remove the installation you do not want. I would suggest removing the one installed with macports or homebrew or whatever you used and keep the MacTeX one, which is probably the `/usr/texbin` one. No. You do not compile the `.bib` file. You just save it where it can be found by Biber. I don't know what quick build is configured to do. But if `pdflatex` and `biber` are from different installations, it won't work.

Comment: I am afraid that uninstallation will crash the whole thing so I may just make sure that they do not mix. I think there is also a `pdflatex` under `/usr/texbin` and I think texmaker use the one `/usr/texbin/pdflatex` as specified in the configuration path in the texmaker preference.  I don't know where does `/opt/local/bin/pdflatex` come from and why does `which pdflatex` points to `/opt/local/bin/pdflatex`  instead of  `/usr/texbin/pdflatex` (which is the one what texmaker use).

Comment: @cfr I did use  `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` without loading `bibtex` but it gives error when I do so. I type `which biblatex` in the terminal and it returns nothing. Does it mean I don't have `biblatex`? `which bibtex` returns `/opt/local/bin/bibtex`.

Comment: `biblatex` is not a binary. It is a package. So `which` will not find it. There are lots of errors. It is impossible to guess what might be wrong from the information you are giving. But read the errors. Read the log file. And remove the installation you do not want.

Comment: @cfr Well, b) I don't know what's the right path, that's the reason why I said that maybe `/usr/bin/` could be not exactly the path. a) If the time is short, although the user has another editor, that script could be helpful. Once in a  similar case I solved the problem in that way.

Comment: @Aradnix My main point was that (1) `/usr/texbin/` is very unlikely to be right on GNU/Linux, and (2) using a different editor will help only if, for some reason, that editor uses a different configuration.

Comment: @cfr (2) or if in that editor the path is mapped well.

Comment: @Aradnix You mean '(2) or if in that editor the path is mapped badly'. The editor should not, at least by default, overrule `PATH` settings. That would make all kinds of things fail in all kinds of mysterious ways. Note that the OP's `PATH` is not wrong: it just is not what is probably wanted here. The path has probably been modified on installation of MacTeX and then modified later by MacPorts (or HomeBrew or whatever the latest thingie is). If there were not 2 versions of TeX Live installed, all would be well.